# Remove comments and blank spaces from arrays without losing the 0

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do i use this

```
//arr.filter(function(e){ 
  return e === 0 || e 
});
```

in my function?

```
function stringToArray(splitString) {
    return splitString.split("\n");
}
```

I made an array to split my string into new arrays but i want to remove blank spaces and comments from going into the array. I also want to keep 0 because i want the program im working on to give me binary when its complete.

Comment: Can you include example string and expected result at Question?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to test each line separately (so no multi-line comments with `/*` and `*/`) then it is easy enough to `.filter()` out lines that are empty strings or that start with `//`:

```
function stringToArray(splitString) {
    return splitString.split("\n").filter(function(v) {
        return v != "" && v.indexOf("//") != 0;
    });
}
```

Or if you want to ignore lines that aren't empty but which contain nothing but whitespace, or lines that have blank space at the beginning followed by comments, you could use a regex test, perhaps something like this:

```
function stringToArray(splitString) {
    return splitString.split("\n").filter(function(v) {
         return !/^\s*(\/\/.*)?$/.test(v);
    });
}
```

Comment: Im trying to make an assembler that takes in a string and converts it into binary. Im looking for a way to make sure all the white space and empty lines arent put into the array if someone decides to hit enter a few times in the textbox or leave comments in the textbox

Comment: I believe my answer covers what you've asked for in the current wording of your question. If you are trying to do something else then please edit your question to show an example input and the corresponding desired output.

Answer (score 1):

May be the following answers your question;

```js
var code = 'some code here; // an a comment\n more code; //comment\n\n\n\n\ some code here; \nafter some empty lines more code; // and comment\n //comment line\n\n\n             tons of space and more code;\n0  code with zero //this line starts with a zero //',
   codar = code.split(/\n+/).map(s => s.replace(/\s+/g,"").replace(/\/\/.+/g,"")).filter(s => s === 0||s);
console.log(codar);
```